# Setting python shell version with .sh file

Tags: bash, python3

I am executing my `./shell.sh` which contains

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
pyenv shell 3.8.2
```

But nothing happens. If i run this code in bash manually it works fine and shell version of python switches from `2.7.10` to `3.8.2`.

I am in the right directory and I gave the `.sh` file execution permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add `pyenv init` to your shell to enable shims and autocompletion. Please make sure `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` is placed toward the end of the shell configuration file since it manipulates `PATH` during the initialization.

<sup>([source](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv))</sup>

The command is designed to manipulate the environment of the shell; and to define some functions. If it's in a script then it will manipulate the environment of (and define functions in) the shell interpreting the script.

If your script is `shell.sh` and you run it with `./shell.sh` (or `bash shell.sh`) then the shell interpreting the script is *not* your current shell. Please see [**What is the difference between sourcing (`.` or `source`) and executing a file in `bash`?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43882/108618)

So don't expect your script to change anything in your *current* shell, unless you source the script:

```
. ./shell.sh
```

Note in this case the file does not need to be executable. The shebang (if any) doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything including pyenv global works fine