# How to activate python virtualenv through shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, python, amazon-web-services

0

I have to activate the virtual environment (venv) so I running these commands manually in terminal:

`source .venv/bin/activate     # To activate the virtual env.`

and

`deactivate                    # To deactivate the virtual env`

This works fine when running manually. Now I have to insert these commands in a bash script to make AWS CodeDeploy to deploy it on a Ubuntu 18.04 server.

My bash script named after_install.sh looks like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
source .venv/bin/activate
## DO SOME STUFF ##
deactivate
```

For local testing, I made the script executable and ran the script using bash after_install.sh. But nothing happened. It doesn't activate the virtual environment. It seems none of the above commands worked while running the bash script.

I am not getting why these commands work when I run them manually but not with a bash script. What is going on? I need to write these commands inside the bash script so that AWS CodeDeploy can deploy it on the server.

Comment: `It doesn't activate the virtual environment` – How exactly do you test this inside the script? My point is: `## DO SOME STUFF ##` obviously does nothing. I don't know `.venv/bin/activate`. Does it output anything when sourced interactively? and doesn't output if sourced in a script? Is this your "test"?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I mean to say when you run `source .venv/bin/activate` manually it activates your virtual env as it can be seen in the terminal that `.venv` has been activated. But when you use the same command inside the bash script it does not activate `.venv`, seems that the command does not have any effect when running bash script.

Comment: Sigh… `as it can be seen in the terminal` – How *exactly*? Do you need the environment in the script? Or outside of the script *after* you "run" it?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Why do you create a bash script? - To run all things automatically just by executing it so that you do not have run each and every command manually. The same thing I am trying to achieve I have to run this command `source .venv/bin/activate` through a bash script which is not running, as I need the env should get activated after this particular script is executed which is not happening.

Comment: There's a difference between expecting something to work in a script and *after* the script. Also note the script contains `deactivate`, so even if you make it affect your current shell, `deactivate` will "win".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ok, let's remove `deactivate` and we are only running `source .venv/bin/activate` through bash script. Now accordingly when I execute the bash script do the environment gets activated or not as mentioned in the script?

Comment: Have you read my answer to the linked question? You need to source the script (`. after_install.sh` or `source after_install.sh`) to allow commands in the script affect your current shell. For the same reason you need to `source .venv/bin/activate` in the first place (and you do), not just `.venv/bin/activate`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have read your answer to the linked question and I know that I have to source the script, but I do not have to execute/source the script by myself. My role is just to write commands in a script and on my behalf, AWS CodeDeploy will execute it on the server and thats when I do not know how the script will behave.

Comment: OK, there is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. I admit I don't fully understand the issue now (I don't know AWS). I'm reopening the question. My advice for you is to [edit] it and state clearly that (1) you want the script to affect something (what?) after the script finishes; (2) and sourcing the script (per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1540981/432690)) is not an option.

Comment: @marshmello I am guessing you need a specific package in this python env? Can you add a command where you try to load a package that is in this env but NOT  in the base env `python -m numpy ... ` or similar. Put this between the activate and deactivate. This should be enough to tell you if the bash works or not

Answer (score 2):

`source file_name.sh`

worked for me as well (as per Dipanwita Mallick's answer).

The full explanation for why this works is provided [here](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it#:%7E:text=Sourcing%20a%20script%20will%20run,in%20a%20new%20shell%20process) by Lesmana.
In summary:

- Sourcing a script will run the commands in the current shell process. Changes to the environment take effect in the current shell.
- Executing a script will run the commands in a new shell process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the full path to virtualenv directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
source /full-path/to/.venv/bin/activate
## DO SOME STUFF -> USE FULL PATH HERE TOO #
deactivate
```

Best regards.

Comment: Word of caution: we probably don't want to use `set -e` here since the script is likely to be used with an interactive shell.  From the Bash manual, the `set -e` option will "Exit immediately if a pipeline, which may consist of a single simple command, a list, or a compound command *returns a non-zero status.*"  The phrase "non-zero status" is UNIX-speak for "error".  When "set -e" is enabled and a command fails, *any* command, the shell will exit. This includes tab completion on commands like `python`.  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin

Answer (score 0):

Use *source* to run the shell script.

```
source file_name.sh
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).